# VLP16 - ROS Indigo- Velodyne poll() timeout Issue

Tags: ros, vlp16, timeout, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I am pretty new with ROS and looking for some guidance. I got this error every time I tried to start the ROS.

```
rosrun velodyne_driver velodyne_node _model:=VLP16
[ERROR] [1478568624.623678583]: unknown Velodyne LIDAR model: VLP16
[ INFO] [1478568624.624140559]: Velodyne HDL-VLP16 rotating at 600 RPM
[ INFO] [1478568624.624584136]: publishing 260 packets per scan
[ INFO] [1478568624.624990083]: expected frequency: 10.000 (Hz)
[ INFO] [1478568624.625052893]: Opening UDP socket: port 2368
[ WARN] [1478568625.626775354]: Velodyne poll() timeout
```

[ WARN] [1478568626.627907945]: Velodyne poll() timeout

I have installed the ROS Indigo Velodyne driver by following this step http://answers.ros.org/question/226594/how-do-i-build-ros-vlp16-velodyne-driver-for-indigo-using-catkin/

Any advise how to resolve this initial problem ? I've ran `roscore` and tried to do `rosrun`.

My goal is to read the real time data from VLP16 using `rviz`

Any advise will be highly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247489/vlp16---ros-indigo--velodyne-poll()-timeout-issue/) by [fair_child](https://answers.ros.org/users/28467/fair_child/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That error suggests that you're running the released Indigo binary Velodyne driver, not the latest sources from github.

If you followed those directions to clone and build the sources, did you forget the final `source devel/setup.bash` step?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [T318forever](https://answers.ros.org/users/30306/t318forever/) on 2017-05-09**:
I have the same problem. I cloned the latest source from github as http://answers.ros.org/question/226594/how-do-i-build-ros-vlp16-velodyne-driver-for-indigo-using-catkin/ shows. I also applied source devel/setup.bash. However, it is still Velodyne poll() timeout

**Comment by [summer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31948/summer/) on 2017-12-28**:
I also have the same question. Do you resolved it? If you have the answer,could you tell me ?